# Option buttons in plugin Dialog

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, plugin, jquery-ui

I used the jQuery UI plugin *Dialog* to ask a user for "name" and to show it in a subsequent dialog.

Is there the better way to add a function to the option "buttons" to get the data and to go to a new dialog?

```
    $("#message").dialog({autoOpen: false});
    $("#form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "What is your name?",
        buttons:{
            "Submit": function(){
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                $("#message").dialog("open");
                var str = $("input").val();
                $("span").text(str);
            }
        }
    });
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#form").dialog("open");
    });     


    <body>
    <button id="btn">Click me</button>
    <form id="form">
        <input type="text" name="">
    </form>
    <div id="message">Hello, <span></span>!</div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your Question

> *Is there the better way to add a function to the option "buttons" to get the data and to go to a new dialog?*

I don't believe there is a "*better*" way, though instead of using an object for the [buttons option](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons), an array could be utilized, which would allow more customization of the buttons. For example, the submit button could have [a custom icon](http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/) added to it and more custom event handlers, like [*mouseenter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter). See the code snippet at the end of this post for an example.

### Feedback

#### Elements without *id*s

Your example contains only one form input (i.e. `<input type="text" name="">`), though it is typically rare to only have one form input. As soon as other text/radio/checkbox inputs are added, the way that is referenced in JavaScript will need to change. I would advise you to always add an [*id*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) attribute to the elements and use those when referencing them in the JavaScript. So that text input could have an *id* attribute like `id="username"`. Then the JavaScript can reference it using that attribute: `$('#username').val()`.

The same is true for the `<span>` element that gets set with the text entered by  the user. It would be wise to also give that element an *id* attribute and use it in the JavaScript code. This actually would prevent the title of the message dialog from getting updated with the name (see screenshot below).

[image: all spans updated]

That happens because `$('span')` matches multiple elements, including the header of the message dialog and the element that follows `"Hello, "`, and then [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) updates all of those matching elements.

#### jQuery DOM ready callback

It is best to wrap the jQuery code in a function called when the DOM is ready. Traditionally that was done with [`$.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) but in the latest versions that is deprecated, in favor of the `$(function() {...});` syntax. That way, all variables will have limited scope instead of being global variables (i.e. on `window`).

#### jQuery references

It is wise to store DOM look-ups (e.g. `$('#message')`) in a variable (or actually, a [constant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) would be semantically better, though [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Browser_compatibilty) can be an issue there...), since  those can be expensive.

So for example:

> ```
> $("input").val()
> ```

could be replaced with

```
usernameInput.val();
```

if a line like the following is added at the beginning of the script:

```
const usernameInput = $('#username');
```

For more tips like these, I suggest reading [this article](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/02/stop-writing-slow-javascript/). I know it is 3 years old and bashes jQuery in the beginning but there are some really useful tips there.

```js
$(function() { //DOM ready callback
    //store references in DOM
    const usernameInput = $('#username');
    const usernameDisplay = $('#username_display');
    //store a reference to the message dialog
    const messageDialog = $("#message").dialog({autoOpen: false});
    const formDialog = $("#form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "What is your name?",
        buttons: [{
            text: "submit",
            icon: "ui-icon-contact",
            mouseenter: function() { //when user starts to hover over button
                $(this).effect('shake', 'swing', 100);
            },
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                messageDialog.dialog("open");
                var str = usernameInput.val();
                usernameDisplay.text(str);
            }
        }]
    });
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        formDialog.dialog("open");
    }); 
})
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
    <form id="form">
        <input type="text" name="" id="username">
    </form>
    <div id="message">Hello, <span id="username_display"></span>!</div>
```